# XPath - Return Element By it's Child Element's Value

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I'm trying to search an XML file.

I want to return an entire element, by one of it's children's values.

E.G.

```
<homes>
    <home>
        <rooms>2</rooms>
        <garden>yes</garden>
    </home>
    <home>
       <rooms>4</rooms>
       <garden>no</garden>
    </home>
</homes>
```

I used CURL to get the contents of the XML file. Next, I do this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($curl_contents); // curl contents are that above.
```

Now, here is how I am searching for home(s) with  4 rooms:

```
$homes = $xml->xpath("//homes/home/rooms[.='4']");
```

`$homes` only contains the values of the `<rooms>` element, of homes that have 4 rooms.

... Whereas, I want to return the entire home element(s) that have 4 rooms.

How do I alter my query to do this, please? thanks.

Comment: `//homes/home[rooms='4']`

Answer (score 0):

The shortest XPath is:

```
//home[rooms=4]
```